# How to get specific columns from a Hibernate join

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm very new to Hibernate. I have defined 2 entities like below. A project can be of one category and a category can have many projects.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    String id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    
    @Column(name="description")
    String description;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Category category;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Project> projects;
}
```

When I try to get projects using below I'm getting all the projects that are there for the category.

```
String hql = "from Project";
Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Query<Project> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery(hql, Project.class);
List<Project> projects = theQuery.getResultList();
```

How can I get only category name and id when I get projects.

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.id, 
       c.name
from project p
left join p.category c
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

However you cannot use the result like before as you do not get the projects anymore, so you'd have to do something like following:

```java
Query query = currentSession.createQuery(hql);
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
```

You will also have to cast the Objects from the list when trying to access them, eg.

```java
result.foreach(o -> System.out.println("Id: " + ((String) o.get(0)) + " category: " + ((String) o.get(1))));
```

If you want something other than String types it might be a little more complicated as the Object types are usually sql datatypes, such as `java.sql.Date` for dates and if you are using `java.time.LocalDate` you'd have to convert it first and can't just cast it to `LocalDate`

---

On another note, why are you unwrapping the `Session` from your `EntityManager`? you can just use the `EntityManager` as well (`entityManager.createQuery(query)`)